# Symfony - how to call next service in chain

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, method-chaining

I want to implement chain of responsibility pattern for authorization in my app. I have created four different chain services for authorization and they depends on which routes user want to access. I have a problem with chaining services. I want to chain services without explicitly naming them. For example:

```
class Authorization1:
public function auth($request){
    if (isThisRoute){
        $this->authorize($request);
     }
     $this->authorization2->authorize($request);  
 }
```

I want to know how can i replace last line:        `$this->authorization2->authorize($request);`   with         `$this->chain->authorize($request);` so chain of responsibility pattern can be implemented completly.

Comment: I don't quite understand, but symfony has a functionality for permissions. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like Laravel middleware code.

Try to learn it: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility

If your really want to use Chain of Responsibility instead of Strategy for your four different services it can look like the follow code (PHP v8.0).

**Interface for chains**

```php
interface AuthorizationRequestHandlerInterface
{
    public function auth(Request $request): bool;

   // Option 2
   public function setNext(AuthorizationRequestHandlerInterface $handler): void;
}
```

**A handler for a condition or state**

```php
class Authorization1 implements AuthorizationRequestHandlerInterface
{
    // Option 1
    public function __construct(private AuthorizationRequestHandlerInterface $handler)
    {
    }

    // Option 2
    public function setNext(AuthorizationRequestHandlerInterface $handler): void
    {
        $this->handler = $handler;
    } 

    public function auth(Request $request): bool
    {
        if (isThisRoute) {
            // Check permissions here or call your private or protected method
            return $this->authorize($request);
        }

        // Option 1: Call the next handler
        return $this->handler->auth($request);  

        // Option 2: Call the next handler if it exists
        return $this->handler ? $this->handler->auth($request) : false;
    }

    private function authorize(Request $request): bool
    {
        $result = false;

        // Your code

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Other handlers looks like previous one.

You may do any operations with your object and return any type of value, but this example uses `bool`.

You should prepare configuration of your services in `services.yml` or another way which you use.

At the end PHP code may look like that:

```php
// Initialization: Option 1
$authNull = new AuthNull();
$auth1 = new Authorization1($authNull);
$auth2 = new Authorization2($auth1);
$auth3 = new Authorization3($auth2);

return $auth3;

// Initialization: Option 2
$auth1 = new Authorization1($authNull);
$auth2 = new Authorization2($auth1);
$auth3 = new Authorization3($auth2);
$auth1->setNext($auth2);
$auth2->setNext($auth3);
// In this way you must add the `setNext` method and use its value as `handler` instead of that constructor value.

return $auth1;

// ...

// A class that has the main handler, like AbstractGuardAuthenticator, Controller, ArgumentResolver, ParamConverter, Middleware, etc.

if ($auth->handle($request)) {
    // when it is authorizable, continues the request
} else {
    // when it isn't authorizable, throws Exception, for example
}

// Different handling order that depends on the options.
// Option 1: Auth3 -> Auth2 -> Auth1 -> AuthNull
// Option 2: Auth1 -> Auth2 -> Auth3
```

As @alexcm mentioned, you should read some Symfony information:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html
- https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html